# ¿Comó pasar array de datos y ademas otros datos como parametros por metodo GET, e insertar el array con un UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 $i = 1;  //inicializa variable contadora de registros, recuperados. en 1

   ?>  
    <form method="POST" action="Capt_Calif.php">
    <?php
    //listado de los alumnos en gpo
     foreach ($alumbosByGpoMater as $alumno): 
    ?>
    <tr>    
       <!-- imprime contador de registros, o numero de registros  -->
      <td><?php if ($i <= $num_rows) {  echo $i; } ?></td>
      <!-- imprime matrticula de alumno  -->
      <td><?php echo $alumno[0];?></td>
      <!-- imprime nombre de alumno  -->
      <td><?php echo $alumno[1];?></td>
      <!-- casillas para capturar caliicaciones  e inasistencias por periodo  -->
      <!-- p1= calificacion periodo 1,  ip1 = inasistencias del periodo  -->
      <!-- envuiandolos como un solo arreglo  -->
      <td><input type="text" name="parcial[]" class="p1" size="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parcial[]" class="ip1" size="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parcial[]" class="p2" size="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parcial[]" class="ip2" size="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parcial[]" class="p3" size="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parcial[]" class="ip3" size="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parcial[]" class="final" size="3"></td>
      <!-- parametros enviados para ser usados en la clausula where,   -->
      <td><input type="text" name="idgpo" value="<?php echo $alumno[7]; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="idalumno" value="<?php echo $alumno[10]; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
      $i++;  //incrementamos contador en 1 luego de cada iteracion del bucle foreach
      endforeach
    ?>   
        </tbody>
       </table>    
       <button type="submit" name="formAlumno" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

```html
?php
//Capt_Calif
require '../../Model/Model_Docentes.php';

$connect = conectar(); //conexion a la bd

var_dump($_POST['parcial']);

if (isset($_POST['formAlumno']) && empty($_POST['idgpo']) && empty($_POST['idalumno'])) {

      $grupo     = $_POST['idgpo'];  //RECIBIMOS 
      $alumno    = $_POST['idalumno'];
      $parciales = $_POST['parcial']; //recibiendo el arreglo con calificaciones e inastencias de los inputs....
      
    
foreach ($parciales as $parcial) {

  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE alumno_grupo 
   SET parcial1 = '".$parcial[0]."', inasisP1 = '".$parcial[1]."', parcial2 = '".$parcial[2]."', inasisP2 = '".$parcial[3]."', 
       parcial3 = '".$parcial[4]."', inasisP3 = '".$parcial[5]."', final = '".$parcial[6]."' 
       WHERE idAlumno = $grupo AND idGrupo = $alumno") or die (mysqli_error($connect));

 
   echo "<br>";
   echo $parcial;  
   }

}  //isset



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esa opción se debería ejecutar sin problemas, pero existe otra opción que es crear inputs `hidden` para los datos que pones directamente en el enlace. Y al hacer los elementos mediante `input` `hidden` puedes enviar un `post` en lugar de un `get`.

Comment: lo checaré muchas gracias por la atención, saludos